# Whats wrong with this code to read file?

Tags: perl

I have been trying to read a file called "perlthisfile.txt" which is basically the output of nmap on my computer.

I want to get only the ip addresses printed out, so i wrote the following code but it is not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

print"\n running \n";
open (MYFILE, 'perlthisfile.txt') or die "Cannot open file\n";

while(<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    my @value = split(' ', <MYFILE>);
    print"\n before foreach \n";
    foreach my $val (@value) {
        if (looks_like_number($val)) {
            print "\n looks like number block \n";
            if ($val == /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:\d{1,5})/) {
                print "\n$val\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
close(MYFILE);
exit 0;
```

And when i ran this code the output was:

```
  running 
  before foreach 
  before foreach 
  looks like number block 
  before foreach 
  looks like number block 
  before foreach 
  looks like number block
```

My perlthisfile.txt:

```
  Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-16 22:59 EST
  Nmap scan report for BoB2.iiNet (10.1.1.1)
  Nmap scan report for android-fbff3c3812154cdc (10.1.1.3)
  All 1000 scanned ports on android-fbff3c3812154cdc (10.1.1.3) are closed
  Nmap scan report for 10.1.1.5
  All 1000 scanned ports on 10.1.1.5 are open|filtered
  Nmap scan report for 10.1.1.6
  All 1000 scanned ports on 10.1.1.6 are closed
```

Comment: Can you add a `print $val` before the if(regex)? Your regex is probably not matching.

Comment: @Konerak print "looks like number" is before regex statement

Comment: Please don’t put the tags redundantly into the title.

Comment: @KonradRudolph , i am sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a few errors, one of which is regex which should have optional part for port number (`:` and following `\d{1,5}`)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  

open (my $MYFILE, '<', 'perlthisfile.txt') or die $!;

my $looks_like_ip = qr/( \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} (?: : \d{1,5})? )/x;
while (<$MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    my @value = split;
    print"\n before foreach \n";
    foreach my $val (@value) {
      if (my ($match) = $val =~ /$looks_like_ip/){
        print "\n$match\n";
      }
      # else { print "$val doesn't contain IP\n" }
    }
}
close($MYFILE) or warn $!;
```

Comment: please ignore last comment its working thank you so much cheers

Comment: could you please give a little explanation, why it works when we use my ($match) is it, i mean why i am not getting error saying nmap is not a number?

Comment: @Manu `if()` will test regex and only if matched will execute `print`. You can use `else {}` branch and report problem, check update..

Answer (score 3):

Several issues here.  As @toolic said, calling `<MYFILE>` inside the `split` is probably not what you want - it will read the next record from the file, use `$_` instead.

Also, you are using `==` with a regex, you should use the binding operator, `=~` (`==` is only used for *numeric* comparisons in Perl):

```
if ($val =~ /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:\d{1,5})/){
```

I suggest that `looks_like_number` is redundant if the regex works.  I suspect that you are using it because `==` gives something like `isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)` depending on the version of perl you are using.

Comment: i have changed split function, and i cannot know if regex is working since there are strings in file, and i am manipulating them like number. so i get errors when i compile

Comment: @Manu: Have you changed `==` to `=~`?  It is probably the `==` that is causing your errors!

Comment: So what errors have you been getting?  Can you update your code in the question please?

Comment: as mpapec found i had a problem in my regex, i was looking for port number as well, cheers

Comment: @Manu:  but there are no port numbers in your sample.  You sure it wasn't just replacing `==`?

Comment: if by sample you mean my perlthisfile.txt yea there were no port numbers, but my regex in the end had it. Should i upload the new code?

Comment: @Manu: better not, it will confuse people that follow

Answer (score 2):

If this is what it looks to be, which is a quick hack to extract IPs, you might get away with something simple such as:

```
perl -nlwe '/((?:\d+\.)+\d+)/ && print $1' perlthisfile.txt
```

Which is to say, not a very strict regex by any means, it just matches numbers joined by periods. If you'd like to only print unique IPs, you can make use of a hash to dedupe:

```
perl -nlwe '/((?:\d+\.)+\d+)/ && !$seen{$1}++ && print $1" perlthisfile.txt
```

With a slightly tighter regex that also matches port numbers:

```
perl -nlwe '/((?:\d+[\.:]){3,4}\d+)/ && print $1' perlthisfile.txt
```

This will disallow shorter chains of numbers, and allow for a port number.

This last regex explained:

```
/(         # opening parenthesis, starts a string capture
  (?:      # a non-capturing parenthesis
    \d+    # match a number, repeated one or more times
    [\.:]  # [ ... ] is a character class, it matches one of the literal 
           # characters inside it, and only one time
  ){3,4}   # closing the non-capturing parenthesis, adding a quantifier
           # that says this parenthesis can match 3 or 4 times
  \d+      # match one or more numbers
 )/x       # close capturing parenthesis (added `/x` switch)
```

The `/x` switch is just so that you can use the above regex as-is, with comments and whitespace.

The logic behind this is simply: We want a string consisting of a number followed by a period or a colon. We want this string 3 or 4 times. End with another number.

The `+` and `{3,4}` are quantifiers, they dictate how many times the item to the left of it is supposed to match. By default, every item matches one time, but by using a quantifier you can change that. `+` is shorthand for `{1,}`, and you also have:

- `? -> {1,0}`
- `* -> {0,}`

The syntax is `{min,max}`, and when a number is missing, that means as many times as possible.

Comment: wao man, that is so awesome, my next step was to actually only print unique IPs, i've never user perl before today is my first time, really like it. That is so awesome that i can actually do that. Much appreciated

Comment: @Manu You can do just about anything in Perl. This is mostly as an example of how you can write quick programs and take advantage of the command line utilities.

Comment: i am going to learn this, but the regex is really terrifying, could please if possible post some useful perl links.

Comment: Personally, I learned mostly from reading the [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/). You might like perlre and perlretut. There are also web services that will explain regexes for you. It's not so difficult once you take it apart.

Comment: much appreciated mate, just want you to know that what you wrote up there has made me want to learn perl like hell. i will definitely look in those version. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Manu Added an explanation of the regex.